# How to remove share menu on embed live stream?

Tags: embed, jwplayer

Please how to remove on pause , share menu , in this embed code ?

```
<script>
                          $(document).ready(function(){ 
                                $('#ansalive_player_mod2').empty();
                                $('#ansalive_player_mod2').flash(
                                    { 
                                      src: '/player.swf',                                    
                                      width: 680,
                                      height: 400,
                                      quality:'high',
                                      allowfullscreen: 'true',
                                      flashvars: { file: 'n24stream?adbe-live-event=news24', streamer: 'rtmp://66.55.93.203/livepkgr/', image: '/news24/live/emisionet/img/live3.png', skin: '', autostart:  'true', volume: '50',  quality:'medium', stretching: 'exactfit' }
                                    },
                                    { version: 2 }
                                );
                            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this copy of player.swf, it does not have the share menu on pause - http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf